# Parse RSS feed to XML using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, rss

Can anyone recommend the best way to parse an RSS feed into variables so that I can use in a styled page?

I would like to parse an RSS news feed in a way that I can use the first two stories to show images/story links - then further links to show story titles only, which once clicked will show the corresponding story.  Therefore I need a parsing method that would allow me to customize the feed rather than render it in HTML on the page.

Any ideas gratefully appreciated!

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0):

RSS is an XML format, and XML can be traversed using the same DOM selectors jQuery uses on an HTML document.

Something like `$('item').slice(0,1)` should get you the first two items.